# Upgrading to TypeScript 2.1 results in Can't resolve 'file' ` errors in previously working project

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader

Since upgrading to typescript 2.1, I seem to be getting a whole load of `Can't resolve 'file'` errors when running webpack

```
ERROR in ./src/Game.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'file' in '/Users/nikos/WebstormProjects/youtube-space-invaders/src'
 @ ./src/Game.ts 32:30-95
 @ ./src/app.js
```

An example of the error location is here:
https://github.com/QuantumInformation/youtube-space-invaders/blob/master/src/Game.ts#L32

```
 32   invaders: AbstractInvader[]
      invaderBullets: Bullet[] = [];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks more like this is the culprit: https://github.com/QuantumInformation/youtube-space-invaders/blob/master/src/Game.ts#L56

Your line number probably refers to the compiled typescript (to verify run tsc in root folder and look at the output).

To solve your problem use an image loader in your webpack config and only require it via require('./images/backgrounds/sunrise.jpg') and you should be fine...

Comment: I tried image-webpack-loader, but need to get the correct syntax. https://github.com/tcoopman/image-webpack-loader/issues/59